# Can't login to newly installed phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpmyadmin on my hosting account, I edited the config file and only changed the 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` value

I see in the config file that the logins are `pma` and password is blank (which are the defaults. But when I try to login with that, I get

`Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)` error.

So I made `['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

But I get another error saying

`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'IP' (using password: NO)`

This really sucks. BTW I have `['auth_type'] = 'cookie'`

I didnt create any MySQL database, as I understand from what I read that I have to create a database for phpMyAdmin logins, but I couldnt find the DB structure that I need, and couldnt find a way to do it.

All I need is to be able to access phpmyadmin with a user name and password on my hosted account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the below changes are made to the `config.inc.php` file that came with phpmyadmin installation

1) I changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` to the value that my host company gave me (usually their server ip)

2) Changed `['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` to `false`

3) Kept `['auth_type'] = 'cookie'` as it is

4) I created a mysql database (any database with any tables and columns will do), this actually was geo lite 2 database (so it is not related what so ever to usernames and passwords and logins stuff)

5) I changed this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'MY_DATABASE_NAME_HERE';`

6) Finally navigate to phpmyadmin login page, and login with the database username and password (the database that I created in step 4).

Hope this helps somebody